# How to normalize colors acquiring a single color?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have to build an algorithm that takes an RBG image and returns the image turned into a wood-like mosaic. For this, I was given some wood tablets samples as seen in the image below:

[image: samples]

I'd like to know how I can normalize the colors of each tablet, resulting in a single color, so I can build a map of reference colors to convert the input image colors to.

I've searched for how to achieve that, but I only found a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_normalization), but I couldn't understand much of it.

Thanks in advance for all help you might provide me.

PS: I'm considering using Python to develop this. So if you come up with something done using this language, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure color normalization is the right thing here? Maybe you should pick the tablet that best matches the input image, then use that tablet’s color map.

Comment: Will you be using those tablets as-is, or can you "stain" them to give them different hues?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the ideia here is to compose the mosaic with many tablets, not only one. I have to map groups of pixels to match a single tablet. I thought of normalization because I wanted to have a single color, that should be visually near the color of the real tablets, so I can more easily map the image's hues to the hues present in the samples.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I have to use them as is. That is why there are tablets of different colors.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the color too much. You don't have very much variation from one tablet to the next in terms of the mean hue, but there's a reasonable range of luminance (brightness). I assume you're using each tablet as a tile, and you can't cut a tile into parts. So first compute the mean luminance of each tablet and save it. Then get your RGB image & convert it to grayscale, and for each pixel find the tablet with the closest luminance.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) has various formulas to convert RGB to grayscale. A simple one from analog TV days that's still often used is `Y = .299*R + .587*G + .114*B`. Or don't worry about doing that arithmetic yourself. Use a graphics package to convert the tablets to grayscale and then just find the average gray value of each one. I assume you know how to calculate the average of a set of numbers. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring, you're right. I'll do this. Still, having the average colors should ease the process of representing the resulting image.

Comment: But, as the question was how to get a single average color from each sample, I should accept @mark-ransom's answer. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: If your question is about obtaining an average color, why do you ask about color normalization?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, sorry for that. I really thought that was the right term to use. Luck of me Mark Ransom figured out what I really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get the average color is to simply take the average of the RGB values.

To get a more accurate average you should do this with linear color values. Usually RGB uses a gamma corrected value, but you can easily undo it then redo it once you have the average. Here's how you'd do it with Python's PIL using a gamma of 2.2:

```
def average_color(sample):
    pix = sample.load()
    totals = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    for y in range(sample.size[1]):
        for x in range(sample.size[0]):
            color = pix[x,y]
            for c in range(3):
                totals[c] += color[c] ** 2.2
    count = sample.size[0] * sample.size[1]
    color = tuple(int(round((totals[c] / count) ** (1/2.2))) for c in range(3))
    return color
```

For the sample in the upper left of your examples, the result is (144, 82, 66). Here's a visual of all of them:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just could not undertand why you've user a "gamma correction" here, since almost the same result can be obtained without raising the pixels values to any power.

Comment: @HiagoPrata with the colors you have here, gamma might be overkill. It's most visible when you're getting an average of black and white - without gamma the average is (127,127,127) but with it's (186,186,186), quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

To make *one* color represent a tile, a simple option would be to find the mean color of a random sample of pixels in a specific tile. You can choose an appropriate sample size as a trade-off between speed and accuracy.

For your specific use case, I'd recommend further division of tiles, say into 3 *columns* (because of the top-to-bottom design of most wood panels). Find the mean color of each column and eliminate any which is beyond a certain measure of variance. This is to try to ensure that tiles such as the right most one in the 4th row don't get mapped to the darker shade.

An alternate approach would be to convert both your input image and these wood tiles in to and carry out your processing in grayscale. The `opencv` library has various simple functions for `RGB2GRAY`conversions.

Answer (score 0):

One trivial way to normalize the colors is to simply force the mean and standard deviation of RGB values in all images to be the same.

Here is an example with the two panels at the top of the left column in the example image. I'm using MATLAB with [DIPimage 3.0](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib), because that is what I know, but this is trivial enough to implement in Python with NumPy, or any other desired language/library:

```matlab
img = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK6VY.png')
tab1 = dipcrop; % Interactive cropping of a tile from the displayed image
tab2 = dipcrop;

m1 = mean(tab1);
s1 = std(tab1);
m2 = mean(tab2);
s2 = std(tab2);
tab2b = (tab2 - m2) ./ s2 .* s1 + m1;
```

[image: the three images: tab1, tab2 and tab2b]

What the code does to the image `tab2` is, on a per-channel basis, to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation. Next, it multiplies each channel by the standard deviation of the corresponding channel of the template image, and adds the mean of that channel.